# Change Boolean value based on the previous state value

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I have created the toggle function where it will change the Boolean value to false. And I am passing that handler function to button, now I am trying to achieve the same by using previous value, the problem I am facing here is I am having a mock data which will have the following structure {[{}]} inside one object I'll have an array inside that I'll have another objects. I have posted the mock and older implementation by selecting only one value from the mock, could any one guide me how to change the boolean value for the mock which I have. Thanks in advance.

```
const custDetail = {
    customers: [
      {
        name: "Abc",
        isCreated: true,
      },
      {
        name: "bcd",
        isCreated: true,
      },
      {
        name: "Dec",
        isCreated: true,
      },
    ],
  };
```

Code:

```
const [creatingCust, setCreatingCust] = useState([custDetail])

const custData = [...creatingCust]
custData[0].customers[0].isCreated = false
setCreatingCust(custData)

//trying to use prevState but I am getting undefined
const onClick = () => {
setCreatingCust(prevState => ({isCreated:!prevState.customers[0].isCreated}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shallow copy the state, and all nested state, that is being updated. I suggest using the customer `name` property to match the customer element in the `customers` array that you want to update. Use `Array.prototype.map` to create a new array reference.

I suggest also just storing `custDetail` in the `creatingCust` state. I don't a reason to nest it in an array.

Example:

```
const [creatingCust, setCreatingCust] = useState(custDetail);

const onClick = (name) => {
  setCreatingCust(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    customers: prevState.customers.map(
      customer => customer.name === name
        ? {
          ...customer,
          isCreated: !customers.isCreated
        }
        : customer
    ),
  }));
};
```

If you *must* have `creatingCust` be an array the process is similar, but instead of shallow copying into a new object you shallow copy into a new array.

```
 const onClick = (name) => {
  setCreatingCust(prevState => [{
    ...prevState[0],
    customers: prevState[0].customers.map(
      customer => customer.name === name
        ? {
          ...customer,
          isCreated: !customers.isCreated
        }
        : customer
    ),
  }]);
};
```

Comment: I am facing some issue when I am using !customers.iscreated , I need to give !customer.isCreated right ?

Comment: @Still_Learning Yes, "iscreated" !== "isCreated". In Javascript variable/property identifiers are case-sensitive. Since your data and state refer to a `isCreated` property that is what you should continue to reference.